# Windows cmdlet over powershell passes but gives access denied over winrm for Cluster aware updating

Tags: powershell, ansible, hyper-v

I am executing `Invoke-CACURun` for windows cluster aware updating on domain controller as an administrator. While that works on powershell, it is failing over ansible with ntlm transport and same credentials.

The command executed

`ansible domain_controller -i ansible_hosts -m win_shell -a  'whoami;Invoke-CauRun -ClusterName "xyzWFC`

The error I get is

> Invoke-CauRun : Could not open cluster "xyzWFC": (Win32Exception) Access is denied
>   At line:1 char:72
>   + ... .UTF8Encoding $false; whoami;Invoke-CauRun -ClusterName "xyzWFC";
>   +                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Invoke-CauRun], CauAccessDeniedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OpenClusterAccessDenied,Microsoft.ClusterAwareUpdating.Commands.InvokeCauRunCommandnon-zero return code

Any help on this?

Comment: Sounds like a [double hop issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen . that solved my problem. i was using ntlm as an authentication method.  Changed it to credssp since its a secure environment and the CAU update is possible from domain controller to the cluster